# JPA one to one mapping FetchType.LAZY is not working

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have two entities like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ticket")
public class Ticket {

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = com.vahana.entity.TicketBookingAdditionalInfo.class, mappedBy = "ticket", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private TicketBookingAdditionalInfo ticketBookingAdditionalInfo;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ticket_booking_additional_info")
public class TicketBookingAdditionalInfo {

    /** The ticket. */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    private Ticket ticket;

}
```

My Ticket table contains 40,000+ records, but ticket booking additional info does not have any data. This table will contain data, only if am going to add additional info.

While selecting ticket table , it joins the ticket_booking_additional_info table and that query takes more time.

I have added fetch=FetchType.LAZY in @OneToOne, but still it takes much time to respond.This is the most time consuming query in my DB. How to avoid this issue.Please some one guide me.

Am using mysql DB,

Comment: Your mapping males no sense. If you have a ManyToOne on one side, you should have a OneToMany on the other side, not a OneToOne.

Comment: Also, according to JPA specifications, FetchType.EAGER defines a behavior that each JPA implementation must comply with while FetchType.LAZY is kind of a hint --> behavior may differ depending on the persistence provider you're using. What JPA implementation are you using?

Comment: Thank you, let me check with OneToMany mapping instead of OneToOne mapping.

Comment: @Akalya let us know if you resolved with below answer. If yes you should mark as solved, alse can you add more details?

Comment: @Xstian - i have done in my local system, it is working fine, after moving this to production environment only i will get the actual result. it will take few more days to move. Sure will update the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ticket")
public class Ticket {

    //Default is lazy
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticket", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<TicketBookingAdditionalInfo> ticketBookingAdditionalInfo;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ticket_booking_additional_info")
public class TicketBookingAdditionalInfo {

    // The ticket. 
    //Default is eager
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    private Ticket ticket;

}
```

**note**
If you have a ManyToOne, the inverse relationship is OneToMany else if you have a OneToOne, the inverse is OneToOne. You should see [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077819/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-2-relationships-the-jpa-way.html) tutorial

- Example of [OneToOne](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne)
- Example of [OneToMany](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)
- Example of [ManyToOne](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne)